# Glassfish eclipse Plugin with jdk 8

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, glassfish-4

Im trying to launch glassfish-4 using glassfish-eclipse-plugin. Unfortunately it does not seem to recognize the JDK-8 Release candidate i just installed (The "Finish" button stays disabled).

[image]

Finish button will be enabled if i select a java 7 jdk

Is there any options to work around this?

Comment: Actually i got around this by first configuring above window using a 1.7.0jdk and then replacing it with 1.8.0 in the filesystem. However eclipse-wtp, m2e-wtp projects facets etc.. is still lacking 1.8 support. So decided to wait for eclipse WTP support for java 8. Comes in late june according to http://wiki.eclipse.org/Luna/Simultaneous_Release_Plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Lambda support works "out-of-the-box" if using below combination of software

**Oracle JDK 8**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

**Glassfish from 4.01 branch**

http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip

**Eclipse 4.4 Luna**

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ (pick the java ee package)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem getting Eclipse Luna and Glassfish to play nicely. I scrapped everything, re-download and installed eclipse-jee-luna-R-win32-x86_64.  And then upon creating a new dyanmic web app in Eclipse I had install a new extension for the server runtime environment.  That extension was the GlassFish Tools extension from Oracle v7.2.1.2014071142.  An Internet connection was required in order for Eclipse to find this.  And Voila!  So far, so good.  Your mileage might vary.