# Java EE Glashfish server issue in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-8

when i try to add a galsshfish sever in eclipse, it shows me the error as 
`"The server runtime require JRE 1.7 or higher"` in my mac machine, even though i have installed Java 8. Please look into below image

[image]

I followed almost all the links in stackoverflow related to this problem, but none of the solution works for me.

Please help me.

**Note: I have downloaded the netbeans with inbuilt plugin of glashfish sever and its working fine.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416098/glassfish-eclipse-plugin-with-jdk-8

Comment: u mean to say i have to install the java 7???

Comment: Yes, currently the glassfish plugin for eclipse doesnt like jdk8 :(